# .NET Image Compression

Tags: c#, .net, image, compression

We have about 1,500,000 JPEG images on a server, some are already compressed quite extensively, others not at all.

I have the option of using VB.NET, C# or even a different tool of some sort.  I know Adobe offers image compression... but we want something that can be automated and also price does matter.

*edit* -> Additionally, the image name and extension must remain the same.

Does .NET offer advanced enough compression that it won't degrade and image's appearance if it has already been compressed enough? Or, will it attempt to compress an image even further, thus degrading it?

Comment: Why was this closed as off topic? Seems very much on topic to me..

Answer (score 3):

It completely depends on the type of image.

Compression typically comes in two forms - lossless and lossy compression.  Provided you use an image format or compress into an archive which uses lossless compression, there will be zero degredation.

Comment: Does .NET offer the control to do either?  Is there a tool that does it better than .NET?  They are JPEG images.

Comment: @adam JPEG (normal jpg) is, by definition, lossy.  You could save as a PNG if you don't want any compression, or place within an archive (.gz, .zip, etc) to compress without changing the original file.

Comment: So if the image name and extension must remain the same... then the image will degrade as compression takes place... no way around it?

Comment: @adam JPEG will always cause more degradation with more compression - some routines (like Adobe's) are better about keeping quality given a size, but they will still degrade.

Answer (score 2):

Recompressing an existing jpeg will result in much less quality. What you should do is to use a minifier like *jpegtran*. It will losslessly optimize your jpegs.